# django get_attname() to return a list with value if attribute is required

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have this code:

```
[header.get_attname() for header in Model._meta.fields]
```

which returns all the attribute names of the `Model` I selected. I want to see if the attribute is required, for example, if the attribute name is a foreign key, the return should be `[('a_foreign_key', 'required'),...]`

right now its only returning `['a_foreign_key',...]`. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "required"? Null values allowed? The field has `blank=False`?

Comment: null and blank is false.